# VS Code Refresh Integrated Terminal Environment Variables without Restart/Logout

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, refresh

If you add/change some environment variables (e.g. PATH) on windows, even after restarting 'VS Code' it will not be available in VS Code integrated terminals.
But if you open that terminal from windows (Command Prompt/Powershell/...) it will have those new/updated values!!

What should I do to refresh those environment variables? (without restart or log-out)

Comment: Simply restarting VS Code works for me.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to run the following line in a new window of one of your terminals (Command Prompt, Powershell, ...):

```
code
```

It will open 'VS Code' once from them.
Now you can close and re-open 'VS Code' again as many time as you want using its normal shortcuts and have your environment variables.

Comment: Could this be marked as the solution? I tried it and it worked for me

Comment: it doesn't work for me. My environment: `VS Code version 1.45.1`, `Windows 10 Pro`

Comment: when we open vs code using code command from directory from cmd, it launches new instance of vs code with fresh cache. 
If you keep doing open/close vs code same instance getting launched, which might be for performance improvement reason which leads older cached settings retained.

Comment: this doesn't work either

Comment: Sad, how did you do it. maybe this time now itt wil not work.

Comment: @JovylleBermudez it does work, I just tried, first check if the terminal you opened has the env variable by doing `$ echo $MY_VAR` if it doesn't return anything then it comes from something else, then in your project folder type `code .` with a dot so that it opens the current folder.

Comment: This is not a reliable fix. I'm adding a location to my `PATH` on a new Windows 11 installation. My open terminal showed my new `PATH` set but if I launched `code` its terminal had my old `PATH`.

Comment: it worked perfectly fine for me +1

Comment: Some note: Cannot use right click menu "open terminal here" to launch the new terminal, otherwise the terminal process is with old PATH

Comment: Thanks for this solution! What a maddening problem. The solution works for me, but it's a bit finicky: it seems like I have to run `code .` in each one of my workspaces from a fresh shell, otherwise when I re-open other workspaces in other ways, say, through the Windows Start menu, they still get the old environment! VSCode really should have a cleaner mechanism to refresh the environment.

Answer (score 11):

This manually resets the path variable in the specific PowerShell terminal.

```
$env:Path = `
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + `
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

Answer (score 9):

Chocolatey comes with a [`RefreshEnv.cmd` utility](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/src/chocolatey.resources/redirects/RefreshEnv.cmd) for this purpose, which worked for me. More convenient than opening other `code` instances.

Comment: It's enough to type RefreshEnv. Or if someone wants it to be even shorter, the file can be found in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\ and can be renamed to whatever.cmd

Comment: This works only for cmd, not powershell

Answer (score 3):

I got the following to work (at least on VS Code 1.62.00).

1. Restart VS Code
2. Open a new terminal (via `Terminal->New Terminal` or `` Ctrl+Shift+` ``  or with the `+` on the top right of the terminal window), do NOT use the existing terminals or `View->Terminal`.

Make sure that you are on the new terminal, as many times after restarting VS Code it might try to restore the old terminal.

The new terminal should be up to date.

Answer (score -2):

The following approach worked for me.

1. Close VS Code
2. Right click the VS Code icon pinned to the task bar
3. Open VS Code again using the "New Window" option

The new environment variable will now be available

[image]