# Can't run java in VSCode terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, path, environment-variables

In VSCode terminal (Powershell and CMD), when I run javac or java I get

> javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

However, when I open a CMD or Powershell outside of VSCode I successfully run them. I'm guessing this is because the path config is messed up for VSCode on my machine, but I can't seem to find where to fix it. How can I make sure my VSCode path env are the same as my System env?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63057245/changing-the-java-home-path-in-vs-code

Answer (score 0):

**Restart VS Code**. VS Code uses integrated Terminal so it should work too if commands can be executed in external terminal.

About your guessing messed path config, you may

1. `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` form Command Palette
2. `Java: Configure Java Runtime` from Command Palette, turn to Java Tooling Runtime then select the installed java which is required to be **java11 or recent version** for `JDK for Language Server`:

[image]

Don't forget to **reload window** to make the change effective.

Comment: This allows me to run my java program by clicking on "run" and "debug", but unfortunately java and javac commands within the integrated terminal still don't work.

Comment: How about adding java to **System-PATH**, is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

Simply open a new cmd, type code to open a new instance of vscode, and from then on the new path variables will be loaded.

**Long form**

I had the same problem after installing java via winget as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/install

After it had installed, I tried `java -version` in a **new** instance of vscode, and it failed with the good old

> 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...

So I tried it in a plain new CMD window, where it worked. Strange...

Rather than restarting the computer or logout/login as suggested in other places (turning off and on again? That's so last century), I found that I had to open a new vscode instance **from CMD**, as described here:

[VS Code Refresh Integrated Terminal Environment Variables without Restart/Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653343/vs-code-refresh-integrated-terminal-environment-variables-without-restart-logout)